# Reading Export commands from Linux script stdin

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a script where I need to input creds with the export command.
I am using read command to get those values in the script.

This is what I need to input when the script asks for input. I want to give entire input at one shot.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXXXXXX"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXXXX"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="XXXXXXX"
```

The portion of the script:

```
   read inputawscreds

  $aws cloudformation get-stack-policy --stack-name=$cloudformation_stack --region=$region | $jq '.StackPolicyBody' > $policy_backup_filename
```

This script takes the exported creds and then use creds to run aws cli.
This script runs in a loop where i need to give set of inputs creds (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN) at each times

Comment: Can you show your script?

Comment: Hopefully those arent your actuall AWS credentials, they are sensitive data that should not be shared

Comment: Also, if you read your variables into a string without the export command before them, you can call export on the whole string at once. I.e. `export FOO=foo BAR=bar`. Typically the read command stores the input in the $REPLY variable, so you could just do `read; export $REPLY`

Comment: What's wrong with `source inputawscreds`?